# Android MotinEvent.getRawX(int pointerIndex) gives nomethod exception

Tags: android, view, motionevent

This is the full error of no such method:

> E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getRawX(I)F in class Landroid/view/MotionEvent; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.view.MotionEvent' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex)

What I am doing -
Inside

```
onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?) {
...some code...
event.getRawX(0)
}
```

In the `event.getRawX(0)` line I am getting that exception.
Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: are you running your code on API level 29+ (android Q)?

Comment: Yes the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are 29

Comment: on what device do you run your code? is it android q?

Comment: Device - MiA1, Android Version 28

Comment: see [getRawX(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getRawX(int)) - you will see on the right side `"Added in API level 29"`

Comment: I checked the androidXref to view the source code of AOSP (8th &9th Version). There is no method in MotionEvent class and I also found that this api is (restricted) not supoorted by using annotation (@UnsupportedAppUsage)

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about, sorry... did you check the link i posted in my previous comment?

Comment: Never mind, thanks I got your point, I can't use this function on below API 29 devices

Comment: found solution ?